# Can I allow paging in the contenttype config

Tags: bolt-cms

I have been playing with the paginator function in Bolt CMS, it is easy to use.

Now I need to know if there is a way to implement the pagination in the contenttype yaml.

I think, is it possible something like this?

```
entries:
  name: Entries
  singular_name: Entry
  fields:
    ...
  taxonomy: [ categories ]
  allowpaging: true
```

I only have found that you need explicity write the allowpaging flag when you fetch the content via setcontent:

```
{% setcontent entries = "entries/latest/4" allowpaging %}
```

But what if you want to use the same template for displaying the related taxonomy records? The problem is that you always will be fetching the last 4 entries regardless the taxonomy.

If there's no way to do this, there would be a way to implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

Paging will also be automatically set if you use listing records setting

```
listing_records: 10
```

But your template still needs a pager that will use this setting - the  listing templates in the theme/base-2014 will work and can be used as an example

The docs have more information https://docs.bolt.cm/contenttypes-and-records#defining-contenttypes

Answer (score 0):

In **config.yml** set `listing_records: xx` or the number of records you want to show

then set in your **.twix** template `{% setcontent entries = "entries/latest/xx" allowpaging %}`with the same number

and add at the end of **.twix** file put this code `{{ pager('pages') }}` to show pages

You can see the official bolt docs for further informations
https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/templating/content-paging